# vue3 input tags giving error Vue.use is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i am using

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@sipec/vue3-tags-input/dist/vue-tags-input.js"></script>
and steps given in 
https://unpkg.com/@sipec/vue3-tags-input/dist/vue-tags-input.js
```

for input tags
in vue 3 standalone page.

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.Vue.use is not a function
```

Comment: You're loading `vue-tags-input.js` before you load `vue.global(prod.).js`. The error is quite self-explanatory. Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve] if you need help.

Comment: Sorry, I have overlooked that you already tried the Vue3 version. Check my second answer. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the playground with [`vue3-tags-input`](https://github.com/engel-learn/vue-tags-input)

The `@tags-changed` event was renamed to `@on-tags-changed`

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const App = {
  components: {
    Vue3TagsInput,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tag: '',
      tags: [],
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  Tag: {{tag}}<br/>
  Tags: {{tags}}
  <vue3-tags-input
      v-model="tag"
      :tags="tags"
      @on-tags-changed="newTags => tags = newTags"
    />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue3-tags-input@1.0.6/dist/vue3-tags-input.min.js"></script>
```